# JavaScript For Loop - For fun, and probably simple

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've recently completed a challenge in Marjin Haverbeke's book, "[Eloquent Javascript, Second Edition](http://eloquentjavascript.net/index.html)".

[One had to create](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#2.1) this console output using a for loop:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######

The answer is this:

for (var i = '#'; i.length < 8; i += '#') {
console.log(i);
}
```

What I would like to know is why the first line is not two hashes ('##') as surely the updating section of the loop (i += '#') adds '#' to i (already = to '#'), therefor meaning that the first iteration of the loop should surely output '##'?

Perhaps I need a lesson on how this loop really works.

Yours truly,
still seemingly JS newbie.

Comment: When the for loop executes, the base case is `#` each iteration thereafter has `#` appended to the current value of `i`.  The loop will execute until the string length is 8.  So in short, the `i += #` happens after each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (init(); condition(); update()) {
  body();
}
```

is equivalent to

```
init();
while (condition()) {
  body();
  update();
}
```

Thus, the first time `i += '#'` runs is only after the first `console.log(i)` (when `i` was just `'#'`).

Comment: Thanks for laying it out like that Amadan. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

@Callum you should first check how for loop works.

if you have written .

```
for (var i = '#'; i.length < 8; i += '#') {
console.log(i);
}
```

so what happen in this loop is this .

1 ) `first var i ='#' initiallize`

then condition

2) `i.length < 8`

then it goes to executed the statement

3) `console.log(i);`

4) `then increment`

```
i += '#'
```

then from step 2 to 4

this is what for loops algorithm works

Answer (score 1):

```
it is just like post increment. The order of execution is:

--> initialisation
--> check condition
--> execute body
--> increment value

so first it would print the value then increment it.
```

Comment: Thankyou Deepak, that makes so much more sense now.

Comment: Your webcome bro :) @CallumOberholzer

Answer (score 0):

This would give `##` in first row:

```
for (var i = '#'; i += '#',i.length < 8; ) {
console.log(i);
}
```